# ObjectDisposedException occuring when getting list from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception

Using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6, I am trying to get a list of all the notifications values a user has from the database. This code did work at one point and now I get an `ObjectDisposedException` when trying to send the list back to the javascript.

Controller method:

```
public JsonResult NotifPrefsOpen()
{
        try
        {
            List<NotificationPreference> notifPreference;

            using (MEDContext MContext = new MEDContext())
            using (StaffContext SContext = new StaffContext())
            {
                AuthorizationUtil au = new AuthorizationUtil(HttpContext, MContext, SContext);
                PreferenceService ps = new PreferenceService(MContext);
                notifPreference = ps.NotificationAllGet(au.EmployeeNumber);

                return Json(new { Success = true , notifPreference});
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            string msg = LogError(GetType().FullName, ex);
            return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = msg });
        }
}
```

Service Method

```
public List<NotificationPreference> NotificationAllGet (int employeeNumber)
{
    IQueryable<NotificationPreference> result = 
           (from n in _context.NotificationPreference
            where n.employeeNumber == employeeNumber
            select n);
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Here is the exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption  mergeOption)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.b__2(TProxy proxy, TItem item)
>   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.NotificationPreferen_93CF7ED7D23D42FE98298039206E4A93E5B136BB3DCBF9EFA5D02A3E8330CADF.get_AppUser()

Comment: This is a prime example of why you shouldn't be using entity object directly in your API.

Answer (score 0):

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.

JSON Serialization is triggering [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#lazy-loading), after the DbContext is disposed.  So disable that, and ensure any related entities you want to serialize are loaded before you construct the JsonResult.

Comment: I still get the error even if the Json statement is taking out of the using clause

Comment: You would.  The issue is that notifPreference is a list of Dynamic Proxies, which retain a reference to the DbContext, and can't be used after the DbContext is disposed.